# set javascript date object to before 30 days

Tags: javascript, date

Lets say now the date is `10/07/2015`, ie If I create a javascript date object like as shown below I will get todays date as `07/10/2015`

```
var now = new Date();
```

So if the date is `10/07/2015` I want 30 days back date i.e `07/09/2015`.

I did like as shown below but for that I got `31/08/2015`

```
var now = new Date();
now .setDate(-30);
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: `var d = new Date("08/18/2009");
 d.setDate(d.getDate()-5);`

Comment: Your date formatting is a mess, you use month first and date first mixed all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
Date.today().add(-30).days();
```

And if you want then moment.js is really good when dealing with dates

```
moment().subtract(30, 'days');
```

And if you dont want to use any library then

```
var now = new Date()
var prev = new Date().setDate(now.getDate()-30)
```

Comment: how about `d.setDate(d.getDate()-30)`

Comment: @BG101:- Updated my answer to get it without any library. However these libaries are helpful for these sort of tasks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have simply use `now.getDate()`:

```js
var now = new Date();
document.write(now);
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 30);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object internally contains a value that corresponds to the number of milliseconds passed since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

As such, using this value (accessible via `Date.prototype.valueOf()`) you can add or subtract any size of "simply calculated" time interval. By simply calculated I mean anything that can be calculated using simple arithmetics, such as (for example..) "*1 day 4 hours and 2 minutes*" is equal to `(((1 * 24) + 4) * 60 + 2) * 60 * 1000`. You can add / subtract that to any starting time and create a new `Date` object:

```js
var startDate = new Date();
var newDate = new Date(startDate.valueOf() + ((((1 * 24) + 4) * 60 + 2) * 60 * 1000));

alert(newDate);
```

In the specific case of days offset, simply use this formula:

```
days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```